# Extjs 4.1 - How to listen window close in grid

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

I have a grid inside a window. I want my `grid` listen when the `window` close I will do reload my `store`.

Any idea? How to do that thanks so much.

Comment: Does the answer below suit your needs?  If so, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a listener to the Window for the close event.

```
...
listeners:{
    close:function(this) {
        this.down('grid').getStore().load();
    }
    scope:this
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-listeners

Comment: This will work, but does not exactly fit his requirements, he apparently wants to listen on the grid according to the statement.

Comment: Yes...I read that wrong.  However the more logical place to put it would be on the.  You could hook it up in a controller using the window alias in the grid controller listening for the close event.